# Radio button select other group button with the same name

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry I do not know english

Radio button select other group button with the same name

That's what I want to do:
The class name selected from group A should be selected automatically in group B with the same name
OR
The class name selected from group B should be selected automatically in group A with the same name

Group A

```
<input type="radio" value="19,186,182" class="NEXT & NEXTSTAR" name="Multiswitch" id="Multiswitch">
<input type="radio" value="96,29,77" class="ETUT" name="Multiswitch" id="Multiswitch">
<input type="radio" value="25,202,43" class="SUNNY" name="Multiswitch" id="Multiswitch">
<input type="radio" value="63,156,69" class="TEKNİKSAT" name="Multiswitch" id="Multiswitch">
<input type="radio" value="240,27,142" class="NEXT" name="Multiswitch" id="Multiswitch">
```

Group B

```
<input type="radio" value="8" class="TEKNİKSAT" name="Amplifier" id="Amplifier">
<input type="radio" value="6" class="SUNNY" name="Amplifier" id="Amplifier">
<input type="radio" value="1" class="NEXT & NEXTSTAR" name="Amplifier" id="Amplifier">
<input type="radio" value="5" class="UZAYSAT" name="Amplifier" id="Amplifier">
<input type="radio" value="11" class="NEXT" name="Amplifier" id="Amplifier">
```

I don't know Javascript at all, can you help?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: ID's must be unique in the document. You should not be giving multiple elements the same ID.

Comment: `class="NEXT & NEXTSTAR"` is not even valid HTML.

Comment: I feel this is not the right site for you. StackOverflow is an English speaking website for programmers (specifically, questions and answers for programming problems). You don't know English and you don't know JavaScript. What are you hoping to find here?

Comment: class="NEXT & NEXTSTAR" Is the problem "&"? or space?

Comment: ` 
var Amplifier = $('input[id=Amplifier]:checked').length;
 ` I use IDs to control

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

Thanks for your help

str_replace() NEXT & NEXTSTAR => next-ve-nextstar

https://jsfiddle.net/ademgenc/b94Ldmp5/9/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('change', "input[type='radio']", function(){

    var name = $(this).attr('class');

    $("." + name ).screwDefaultButtons("check");

    });

</script>
```